# How to understand the member testing and adding race condition of NSMutableSet?

Tags: objective-c, race-condition

When I reading the book 《Objective-C 2.0 Phrasebook》, There is something about NSMutableSet that I don't really understand, as follow,

> There is a potential race between testing whether the string is in the
>   set and adding the new one if it isn’t. A thread-safe version of this
>   would require you to acquire a lock after the `-member:` call, send this
>   message again, and then ﬁnally release the lock after adding the new
>   object.

I don't understand why I should

> send this message again

Does it mean I should make the `-member:` call again? Please help me.
Any code examples will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, an expression like `[mySet member:candidate]` sends the “message” named `member:` to `mySet` (the “receiver”) with the argument `candidate`. It’s often referred to as a “method call” or just a “call”, but [it’s more properly called “sending a message”](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1) or a “message send” because there’s considerably more machinery (and opportunity for customization) in an Objective-C message send than in the method calls of more common languages like C++ or Java.

So yes, when the book says “send this message again”, it means to do `[mySet member:candidate]` again. I haven’t seen the book, but your quote is describing the “double-checked locking” pattern.

However, what the book is describing is **not sufficient** to avoid race conditions if you’re accessing the same `NSMutableSet` from multiple threads (and not needed if you only access the `NSMutableSet` from a single thread). The problem is that, if you say `[mySet addObject:newMember]` on thread A, it is **not safe** to access `mySet` simultaneously from thread B. During the execution of the `addObject:` method, the set may be in an internally-inconsistent state that could (for example) cause a simultaneous `member:` call on another thread to crash. You must lock **read** accesses to `mySet` in addition to write accesses, so the double-checked locking pattern isn’t sufficient protection for sharing an `NSMutableSet` across threads.

The best way to handle this is to use a `dispatch_queue_t` to manage exclusive access to the `NSMutableSet`, and not worry about anything more sophisticated unless the profiler tells you that it’s a bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, Actually speaking, I feel confused because I  don't know the “double-checked locking” pattern, and the book just describes the pattern. Now I've learned the locking pattern, but I still have a doubt why the double-check is needed. Is it trying to prevent the condition changed from another thread while obtaining a lock?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what it is for.